# Warning: include(../config/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream in PHP

Tags: php

i'm getting following error in my PHP file.

`Warning: include(../config/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No 
 such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-proj\functions\function.php on line 2`

let me describe my folder structure

1. ROOT folder /index.php
2. functions / function.php
3. config / config.php
4. signup / signup.php

now, If i use absolute path, then it is give the same error in signup.php, and if I use relative path then it is giving this error in index.php

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you know to ask question why don't you accept the answer? is it because you didn;t get any solution for your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/config/config.php");
```

Answer (score 3):

The file paths are relative to the *invoked* script. If your application gets invoked by http requests to `index.php`, then the `include()` path needs to be relative to that - even if the include statement itself is located in the functions.php script.

A common workaround is to make all paths absolute in relation to the document root:

```
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/config/config.php");
// Note: leaving out array keys only valid in double quote string context.
```

That would work in index.php and functions.php alike.

Comment: thanks for reply mario, what change should I do to overcome this problems?

Comment: Worth noting that you can build paths off of __FILE__ to make paths pseudo-relative to a script instead of execution path.  include dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_) . '../blah.php';

Comment: @ManojNakum: The other option is constructing relative paths as Corbin said, or even setting up the `include_path=` to ease dealing with related scripts. I just gave you the DOCUMENT_ROOT approach, because that also explains the root folder issue I presumed in your question.

Comment: thanks once again mario, now i'm getting following error Warning: include(C:/xampp/htdocs/config/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\my-proj\functions\func.php on line 2

Comment: @ManojNakum: Okay, in your case you have another subdirectory below the document root. You need to mention that too: `include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/my-proj/config/config.php");`

Comment: Ha. Thanks. But also remember the [`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/set_include_path) option. That might become more convenient the more scripts you add to a project.

Answer (score 0):

Use `include __DIR__."/../config/config.php";` if you want to include a file relative to the file you're currently executing in. If you're using a version of php older than 5.3.0 (you shouldn't), replace `__DIR__` with `dirname(__FILE__)`.

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not set when using commandline and requires that your project is relative to the DOCUMENT_ROOT instead of allowing the user to place it wherever they please. If phpMyAdmin used this variable, you would be forced to accommodate it instead of just placing it wherever you want. That's another thing, it's a variable, so there's a potential security issue too.

If config.php is necessary, I suggest using `require` instead, otherwise use `if (file_exists($file)) {require $file;}` so you can avoid warnings when it doesn't exist and get an error when it can't be read (I assume if it exists, it's intended to be used).

Comment: aaand if config.php is required once, require_once()

Comment: (include|require)(_once)? is a language construct, not a function, thus doesn't need parentheses. On top of being unnecessary, I prefer to not use them in order to make that apparent to others.